# EXC_BREAKPOINT on NSFetchedResultsController.performFetch() because of -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm running into a repeatable crash when calling -performFetch on my NSFetchedResultsController in what SEEMS like a data-related crash:

```
 NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:sectionnamekeypath
                                                       cacheName:cacheName];
        

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
if (NO == [aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

It crashes at the performFetch() call. I turned on Zombie checking and it printed:

```
*** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12c6071d0
```

I've checked all of the strings in my function and I can't find a string that has that address. I NSLog()'d all of the strings along with their address locations. I figured it would break on whatever NSLog() line that referenced the string in question, but all of them were still valid.

This makes me think this is a problem inside NSFetchedResultsController.performFetch() but it's hard to imagine that they have this kind of bug. So, what else can I do to find out what string this is?

I haven't run into problems like this since we switched over to ARC. I'm not sure how to figure out where this string comes from.

It SEEMS like this is data related though. My app pulls down data from our server, imports it into Core Data, and then uses the NSFetchedResultsController to show the data in a UITableView. I can login as various different users, download their data, and the FRC fetches and works just fine. But when I login as this one particular user, then it crashes. That user is one of our biggest users and their dataset is thousands and thousands of records, so it's not something I can easily look through to visually find things that might be weird. Doing further testing and will update this if I find any new info.

Comment: I’m pretty sure if it was your code that you’d see it in every case, not just the one. If this doesn’t crash without zombies enabled, I’d file a bug with Apple and move on.

Comment: I'm convinced this is an Apple bug and I'll try to pare it down to a small and repeatable example. I narrowed down the 4000 records to just 3 that will cause it to crash. One of the records has smart quotes in one of the strings (shouldn't be a problem but its the only weird thing). The other two don't have anything weird in them. If I have A+B+C in my database, it crashes. If I have any combination of just two, it works fine.

Comment: That’s good research. If you could verify that the smart quotes trigger the crash, you might be able to work around it by cleaning up the incoming data a little before using it.

Comment: @TomHarrington It took me all night and all morning, but I actually found the issue and it's absolutely mind-boggling that this could have been the problem. My section name key path referred to a function that would return the uppercased firstletter of the name in the record (so the sections would be by A, B, C, D, etc). The -uppercaseString function is what was giving me a reference that would end up being the zombie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have -no- idea how this could have been the problem and potentially someone who understands the relationship between NSString and CFString could explain it to me.

My FRC (NSFetchedResultsController) took a `sectionNameKeyPath` to the initializer so that it would automatically break up the results into appropriate sections for my table view.

The `sectionNameKeyPath` was `namefirstletter` which is a method that I have defined in the base class of all of my Core Data objects.

In my `-namefirstletter` method, I had this code at the end:

```
NSString *uppercasefirstletter = [firstletter uppercaseString];
return uppercasefirstletter;
```

This code has been working for 6+ years, never had a problem. But it's suddenly a problem, so I'm wondering if there was a change in the latest iOS or something. Now, when I execute my FRC with the above code in my sectionNameKeyPath function, it crashes every time.

However, this fixed it:

```
NSString *uppercasefirstletter = [NSString stringWithString:[firstletter uppercaseString]];
return uppercasefirstletter;
```

Now it works every time.

Is `-uppercaseString` returning me an improperly managed reference? Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I would experiment with doing the `[NSString stringWithString:...]` dance before invoking uppercaseString. Does that also solve the problem? In that case I think you'd be able to pin it on something with `firstLetter` instead.

Comment: Since the problem is reproducible, you could probably use the allocations instrument to investigate the deallocated instance and find out why it happened. With a workaround in hand though, I'd get it if you didn't want to dig that deep.

Comment: Also, I suggest filing a bug with Apple and posting the number here, because I have a feeling certain people would be interested to hear about this.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's a known bug with iOS 16.1 and 16.2: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717047